# Connecting Node.js to Redis within docker "Error: The client is closed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, redis

`docker-compose.yml` has something like this:

```
version : "3"
services:
  irbredis:
    image: redis:7.2.2-alpine
    container_name: irbredis
  irbserver:
    image: node:20.9.0-alpine
    container_name: irbserver
    depends_on:
      - irbredis
```

and somewhere in the node.js container, I got this:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const rclient = redis.createClient({ url: "redis://irbredis:6379" });
```

The redis server is definitely running, I can expose port from docker-compose and go to URL to check besides logs. But from node.js codes, I get error log:

```
irbserver  | Error: The client is closed
irbserver  |     at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:494:31)
irbserver  |     at Commander.commandsExecutor (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:189:154)
irbserver  |     at BaseClass.<computed> [as get] (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
irbserver  |     at Object.get (/app/node_modules/connect-redis/dist/cjs/index.js:20:34)
irbserver  |     at RedisStore.get (/app/node_modules/connect-redis/dist/cjs/index.js:53:42)
irbserver  |     at session (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:485:11)
irbserver  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
irbserver  |     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
irbserver  |     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
irbserver  |     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

More context/node.js code:

`redisFunc.js`

```
const redis = require('redis');
const rclient = redis.createClient({ url: "redis://irbredis:6379" });

module.exports =
{
    rclient : rclient
}
```

which is used in
`sessionMW.js` :

```
const session    = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default;

module.exports =
session
(
    {
        store: new RedisStore({ client : require('./redisFunc.js').rclient }),
        //...
    }
);
```

which gets used in `index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();   

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(require('./sessionMW.js'));
//...
```

versions:

```
"connect-redis": "^7.1.0",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"express-session": "^1.17.3",
"redis": "^4.6.10",
```

Comment: "I can expose port from docker-compose" But no ports are exposed in your config file?

Comment: Add   

 `ports:
      - "6379:6379"
under irbredis` in your compose.yml

Comment: If I do `ports: - 6379:6379` and go to `localhost:6379` in my browser, the docker log shows redis getting scared `irbredis   | 1:M 26 Nov 2023 20:27:02.422 # Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection from 172.19.0.1:36238 aborted.`, the problem remains

Comment: Sure, so redis isn't expecting to be accessed over http. But does your application code work? As in, code from your node container should be able to access the hostname `irbredis:6379`?

Comment: No, I get the same error

Comment: Are you waiting for `client.connect()` to resolve before trying to use the connection?

Comment: I forgot to connect, adding `rclient.connect()` fixed it. Thanks! (If you add it as answer, I can accept it, otherwise I'll delete the question later.) @SoZettaSho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With docker-compose networking (or docker in general) usually the first thing you need to do is expose the necessary container ports. In this case, you want containers on the default network to be able to access port 6379 on the `irbredis` container, so you would need to (at the minimum) add something like

```
    ports:
      - "6379"
```

To the configuration for the `irbredis` service.

At this point if you're still getting connection closed issues (and you can verify that the networking is up and accessible from within the application container, which would typically involve something like running an interactive shell in that container and sending a ping to that port), the next thing to look at are errors in your application code (e.g. forgetting to connect, or trying to use a connection before it is ready).

Comment: `expose:` is an obsolete artifact of first-generation Docker networking, and it does approximately nothing.  If you have this option it's safe to remove it; there's no reason to add it.